# Make NginX serve different pages depending on the IPv4 encoding base

Tags: nginx, ip, virtualhost, ipv4

You can access google on 186.215.155.54 , 0xBAD79B36 or 3134692150 (remember to put http:// before if you want to try).

How is the base conversion handled by the browser? Is there any way for NginX to serve different pages from the same IP depending on how it was requested?

I know this might seem useless and I probably should use domain names / subdomains to do this, but it could be a nice trick for an easter egg.

Answer (score 2):

I initially thought this was not possible, but after Ladadadadas comment I got curious and tested it.
It depends on the browser (all tested on a Mac OS X):
Firefox and Safari pass the Host header on, you can detect it.
Chrome and Opera convert it to the IP address, you cannot detect it.

Basically for Firefox/Safari you can check the `Host` header and display different content.

Comment: The web browser will still put the IP address in the `Host:` header exactly as it is written in the URL bar won't it?

Comment: @Ladadadada good point, see my edit: it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to a backend application that does the crazy-ass magic based on the HOST header.